# NGINX not setting Cache-Control header consistently

Tags: linux, nginx

I am having trouble getting NGINX to send cache control headers correctly based on mime type. It works for some types but not for others. What am I missing?

In my `site.conf` file I have:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                    1h;
    text/javascript             1h;
    application/javascript      1h;
#    ~image/                    1h;
    image/webp                  1h;
    image/png                   2h;
    ~font/                      1h;
}
server {
    server_name  ...;
    ...
    root /var/www/site;
    index index.html;

    expires $expires;   
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    ...
}
```

Using images works perfectly. It also works with the `~image/` pattern.

```
curl -I https://site.tld/images/image.webp
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 14:37:16 GMT
content-type: image/webp
content-length: 9488
accept-ranges: bytes
expires: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 15:37:16 GMT
cache-control: max-age=3600
strict-transport-security: max-age=2628000; includeSubDomains

$ curl -I https://site.tld/images/image.png
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 14:37:25 GMT
content-type: image/png
content-length: 53676
accept-ranges: bytes
expires: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 16:37:25 GMT
cache-control: max-age=7200
strict-transport-security: max-age=2628000; includeSubDomains
```

But it refuses to work with CSS or javascript...

```
$ curl -I https://site.tld/css/bootstrap.min.css
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 14:43:39 GMT
content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8
content-length: 162264
vary: Accept-Encoding
accept-ranges: bytes
strict-transport-security: max-age=2628000; includeSubDomains

$ curl -I https://site.tld/js/bootstrap.min.js
HTTP/2 200 
server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
date: Thu, 22 Sep 2022 14:43:53 GMT
content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
content-length: 62563
vary: Accept-Encoding
accept-ranges: bytes
strict-transport-security: max-age=2628000; includeSubDomains
```

The application is a compiled Go app with image assets compiled in and served through the proxy. But all the assets are compiled in, images and CSS, etc. So why does it work for some types and not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content-type that you are trying to set cache has charset. This should also be part of the rule:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                    1h;
    text/javascript             1h;
    application/javascript      1h;
#    ~image/                    1h;
    image/webp                  1h;
    image/png                   2h;
    ~font/                      1h;
    "text/ccs; charset=utf-8"   1h; 
    "text/javascript; charset=utf-8" 1h;
}
```

Otherwise it will fall under the `default` setting.